# Caching side effects

Tags: scala, cache, scalaz

Is this a proper way to cache side effects (occurring on `job.tryLoad`)?

```
case class DFStorage(private var cache: Map[String, DataFrame] = Map()) {
  def tryLoad(job: Job): Kleisli[IO, MakeContext, \/[List[String], Unit]] = {
    if(!cache.contains(job.id)) {
      job.tryLoad.map(_.map(df => add(job, df)))
    } else {
      IO(().right[List[String]]).liftKleisli
    }
  }
  def add(job: Job, df: DataFrame): IO[Unit] = {
    IO(cache += (job.id -> df))
  }
  def toMap = IO(cache)
}
```

Comment: Is the `IO` something internal? I can't find any documentation for it.

Comment: @gardenhead `scalaz.effect.IO`

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me.

Although, having `cache` as a simple `Map` might lay claim to more memory that you like. Associating an LRU with it would allow each addition to evict an ancient job's cached dataframe.